# Is the fancy script 'C' $\mathscr{C}$ available in Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, character-encoding, unicode, named-characters

In mathjax \mathscr{C} gives me the character $\mathscr{C}$ that I want.  There is a UTF listing for this character. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D49E

If I copy form this webpage and paste into a notebook, it shows up as "|01d49e".  It looks correct(not pretty), but acts like two characters when trying to copy and paste.  That spells trouble, since it is too easy to forget that idiosyncrasy while editing.

Is there a better way to produce a mathematical script 'C'?  It is very common in mathematical literature.

Comment: There is a [script capital C](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/ScriptCapitalC.html) listed here: [Notational Alphabet Characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NotationalAlphabetCharacters.html). It's not nearly as curly and pretty in a standard notebook, but it might do.

Comment: Then what do I call the origin-centered cube of radius $r$? And the origin-justified cube of edge-length $d$?  The \[ScriptCapitalC] maps to $\mathcal{C}$ of LaTeX.

Comment: If you mean to say that you would use the same symbol for both of those objects, then that's an argument *against* using the symbol, which might generate ambiguity. In fact, using more descriptive names instead of a symbol whose interpretation may be discipline-specific will make your code more readable.

Comment: Similar problem here (but no good solution yet): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193668/why-do-i-get-different-symbols-a-with-the-same-fontface-cambria-math — My own opinion is that these glyphs are currently mishandled and WRI should improve its Unicode support. User feedback can influence their priorities, so consider reporting it through Help > Give Feedback...

Comment: `FromCharacterCode[119966]` converts the Unicode code to  on Wolfram Cloud, but it returns a two-character string on the desktop version (12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)).