# How to display Latin Modern Math font correctly in Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, latex, fonts

I just used [Latin Modern Math](https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download) font to display $\LaTeX$-like formulas in Mathematica.
My expected effect is shown as follows:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
Style["f(x)=\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \
\(n\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(n\)]\)/n)", 
 FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]
```

I get this result:

[image]

It doesn't meet my expectation. How can I display formulas in Mathematica like in $\LaTeX$?

Comment: Use `$FontFamilies` to get a list of all font families available. Is `"Latin Modern Math"` indeed in the list? Perhaps it has a different name. See also [MaTeX package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).

Comment: @Domen You can download it from https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is on my computer, I am asking whether it shows on _your_ computer. Evalute `$FontFamilies` and check it, please.

Comment: @Domen  I didn't expect you to ask this low-level question, because installing and checking if fonts are installed is a very basic operation.

Comment: *MaTeX* gives $\LaTeX$ style typesetting in *Mathematica*.  I wish WRI would buy this technology from its developer and incorporate it into their next release.  http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Latex is free and open source software. WRI can implement this if they want in one day. They just have to bundle the latex engine as part of Mathematica and use it internally. Mathwork has done this more than 30 years ago in Matlab. see [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.text-properties.html#budt_bq-1_sep_shared-Interpreter). Latex is build in Matab. No need to install or do anything by the user. But WRI does not want  to do this, because they want people to use Mathematica's own way of doing things when it comes to styling.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193668/1871

Comment: What platform wind, Linux or Mac?,

Answer (score 7):

## Practical solution

Just use [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).

## Explanation

There is in fact—more or less—nothing really wrong with what you see. If you compare the same text to the one written in some other word processor (e.g. Word), you will see that the *letter glyphs* (though not the math and greek symbols*), such as `f`, `x`, and `n`, are the same:

[image]

---

Why is this not displayed the same as it is in $\LaTeX$ equations, even though it is supposed to be the correct font? Because Latin Modern Math is a "special" font that contains many (4802) different glyphs, and it is not meant to be used as other typical fonts that you download and use to style your text. You can see all of the glyphs by using, for example, an [online font viewer](https://fontdrop.info/) (upload the *latinmodern-math.otf* file). Look, under the usual Unicode code `0066` which stands for `f`, there is the up-right character f that you see in the output. But the italic "math-like" one is stored under the Unicode code `01D453`:

[image]

Therefore, to get the "math-like" characters, you have to type them in using their correct Unicode codes:

```
Style["\|01d453(\|01d465)=\|01d465/\|01d45b", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]
```

[image]

Using `PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}` fixes the display of math symbols:

```
Style["\|01d453(\|01d465)=\|01d465/\|01d45b", 
 FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", 
 PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]
```

[image]

---

* If you use a text style cell with Latin Modern Math, even the math characters (but [not the Greek ones](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84968/using-greek-latex-fonts/208125)) are rendered correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have written a Mathematica function (`DispLaTeX`) that uses `ImportString` from `LaTeX` format, and then some postprocessing (converting the `Cell`s, `BoxData`, and `TextData`, etc.)  It does not use an external library, so it does not produce as nice an output as MaTeX, nor does it implement all of $\LaTeX$, but it is lightweight and does not require installation.

`Style[DispLaTeX["$$f\\!(x)=\\sum_n\\left(x^n/n\\right)$$"], FontSize->16, FontFamily->"Latin Modern Math"]`

produces

[image]

applying `InputForm` gives

`Style[DisplayForm[RowBox[{StyleBox[RowBox[{}]], StyleBox[FormBox[RowBox[{StyleBox["f","I"], "\[NegativeThinSpace]", RowBox[{"(", StyleBox["x","I"],")"}], "\[LongEqual]", UnderscriptBox["\[Sum]", StyleBox["n","I"], LimitsPositioning->False], RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[StyleBox["x","I"],StyleBox["n","I"]], "/", StyleBox["n","I"]}],")"}]}], TraditionalForm]]}]], FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]`

Comment: I thought that posting the code for `DispLaTeX` was not on-topic here, but I can provide it if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Domen has already given a nice explanation for the topic [in his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288219/1871), I just want to add that, the scope of influence of the encoding issue seems to be limited to the 52 English letters, in other words, though it's not easy to achieve **exactly** the same effect as $\LaTeX$ in *Mathematica*, it's not too hard to make the font right, we just need to make a replacement. Here'a possible implementation:

```
range = 16^^1d434 + Range[0, 51];
(* Notice the h is special: *)
codelst = ReplacePart[range, {34} -> 16^^210e];

rhs = FromCharacterCode[#] & /@ codelst;

lhs = Flatten@{ToUpperCase[#], #} &@Alphabet[];

rule = Thread[lhs -> rhs]
```

[image]

```
display = Function[expr, 
   Style[MakeBoxes[expr, TraditionalForm] /. rule // DisplayForm, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], HoldAll];

display[f[x] = Sum[x^n/n, n]]
```

[image]

You can then make the fraction 1D via manual edit:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TraditionalForm[Style[f[x] == HoldForm[
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n\)]\)x^n/n], FontFamily -> #, 
    FontSize -> 24, Bold]] & /@ {"Tahoma", "TimesNewRoman", 
  "Helvetica",
  "Times", "Courrier", "Arial", "Veranda"}
```

[image]

Have fun!