# FontFamily output font does not match font name

Tags: fonts

There is a font named **XITS** in my computer. And the percent with it is

[image]

However, in Mathematica, `Style["%", FontFamily -> "XITS", 20]` output it as **Times New Roamn**. So, where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you mount your font?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How should I mount font in Mathamtica? Doesn't it automatically call the system font？

Comment: Where can we get that font? Anyway, if I have to guess, this may be related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/288212/1871

Comment: @xzczd  Here: https://github.com/aliftype/xits

Comment: I see 6 fonts in the link. Which one are you using?

Comment: @xzczd This one: `XITS-Regular.otf`

Comment: @xzczd Yes. You are right. Now it seems that it is a problem with the percent symbol and not the font. Thanks a lot.